# Initialize non-null properties using a method instead of constructor

Tags: c#, null

In our architecture we have a method which is always invoked prior to invoking any other method. This method is intended for initializing references which are not available when the object is constructed.

Here is an example of such a class:

```
#nullable enable
public class MyClass
{
    private MyReference _reference; // this shows a warning
    
    public MyClass() { } 

    public void Activate()
    {
        _reference = new MyReference();
    }
}
```

Right now I get warnings on the private field because it is not initialized in the constructor (which makes sense).

There are 2 solutions that I already tried, which are just not quite doing it for me:

1. Make the field nullable. However this means that everywhere where I try to access the field, I have to do a null-check
2. As seen in the code sample, mark all fields that are initialized in `Activate` as `= null!`. This removes the error, however we do not enforce the actual initializing anywhere.

My question is the following: **Is there any attribute or method to make this example work, where I get both forced initialization (by way of compiler warnings) when initialization of my class' fields happen outside of the constructor**

*edit*: Fix formatting of the question

Comment: How about calling `Activate` in the constructor? If you do that, `MemberNotNullAttribute` would help.

Comment: The compiler can handle this only for constructs it knows about, and these are the constructor and an object initializer. There is nothing special about your `Activate` method, so the compiler cannot make sure it is called before anything else.

Comment: What I am reading out of this is that the object is created but not yet fully initialized till later on. Would then be a builder pattern useful? That way you even have the clear distinction between fully initialized object and the intermediate state.

Comment: @Fildor I agree, this could be a good approach. However since this is part of our framework we have to add this for every single class. This could result in quite some verbose code.

@Sweeper The idea is that this is handled by our framework and that initialization of the object happens prior to invoking the `Activate`.

Comment: @KlausGütter I agree with your statement, as said in the question I have also determined that this is the case.

However look at other frameworks, we have Unity for example that does a similar thing where Unity defines a lifecycle that you must adhere to within that framework. This is a similar situation

Comment: How do you ensure that Activate will definitely be invoked after construction?

Comment: @shingo that is handled by the framework we’re using